# prevent duplicate username/password challenge on Windows Auth in subdomains

Tags: iis, sharepoint, windows-authentication

I have a SharePoint On Premises server which uses Windows Authentication.
We also use multiple services which are located on subdomains ie:

documents.mydomain.com
search.mydomain.com
portal.mydomain.com

When we are in the domain it works fine, the username/passsword is determined from the logged in user. However when we are outside the domain we get challenged for a username/password for every subdomain.

- All subdomains are just IIS C# MVC webpages.
- I have added the same MachineKey to every subdomain
- I have added Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: mydomain to the subdomain headers
- I use the follow ajax call:

  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
          xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: true
          },
          url: "https://documents.mysubdomain.com",
          crossDomain: true,
          success: function(response){ console.log("response")}
     })

is it possible to make it share widows/username ntml creds across subdomains

Comment: Can you describe further what is "when we are outside the domain"? Kerberos can work as SSO, while NTLM won't.

Comment: ok. so i require Kerberos. thats what I needed to know

Comment: Outside domain means not on a computer that is logged into windows domain